# Angular page with moodle integration

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, iframe, deployment, moodle

I'm not very experienced in programming, but I'm working on a project for a friend's music school. It involves creating an Angular web page that is more informational and visually pleasing, with some functionality. This Angular page is connected through iframes to a Moodle page where teachers can create courses for students. My idea is for students to access the Angular page and, upon clicking the login button, be redirected to the Moodle login page. Similarly, I'd like direct access on the Moodle page to redirect to the Angular page. I want to know if this is a safe and effective way to build the project. If it is, I'm also curious if it's okay to deploy both pages on an AWS EC2 instance.

For the moment I tried this method on my machine and it seems to work fine, now i want to deploy it, and want to be sure that is a safe way of bulding this project.